# Hide a file extension using Terminal

Tags: command-line, osx, osx-finder

I have about 40 files in my folder. I selected all the files and pressed command+I. Instead of opening one Get Info window, my Mac shows up 40 windows! Is there a terminal command to hide the file extension from being shown when I open this folder in Finder the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the other stack exchange forum "Super User". It looks like this is not possible in Terminal, unless we have Xcode installed or via AppleScript.

[Show/hide extension of a file through OS X command line](https://superuser.com/questions/399899/show-hide-extension-of-a-file-through-os-x-command-line)

Comment: When I tried clicking on the tick mark, I got a message "you can accept the answer in 7 hours".. I think I can mark it only after 7 hours